# Zipping Sub-folders

Tags: powershell, 7-zip

I want to use 7-Zip to zip subfolders to another folder on the same drive.

Each sub-folder has zillions of text files.

I just want to zip subfolder as a whole via Powershell.

I have a script but not working and no error neither.

(`C:\backup` contains some sub-folders, only want to zip subfolders under `:\backup` to `c:\archive` folder.)

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {
       throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"
} 
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$files="c:\backup"
$target="c:\archive"
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $files | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -eq "Directory" }

Foreach ($dir in $dirs)
{
      $name = $dir.name
      $newname = $name.ToLower() -replace(" ","")
      sz a -t7z "$target\$newname" "$files\$dir"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function create-7zip([String] $aDirectory, [String] $aZipfile){
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$aZipfile", "$aDirectory", "-r";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
}
$files="c:\backup"
$target="c:\archive"
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $files | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -eq "Directory" }

Foreach ($dir in $dirs){
      $name = $dir.name
      $newname = $name.ToLower() -replace(" ","")
 create-7zip $files $target.zip


}
```